# Does Cray mpich have a 64 bit integer MPI variable?

Tags: 64-bit, mpi, cray

I am using cray-mpich/7.4.0. When I do

```
 printf("Size:%d",sizeof(MPI_UINT64_T));
```

It print 4 instead of 8. Why is that? The cluster machine is 64 bit for sure.

I have tried this with openmpi/1.10.2 on another cluster and that prints 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous answer is right. But you really should use `MPI_Type_size`.

```
MPI_Type_size(MPI_UINT64_T,&tsize);
fprintf(stderr,"Size:%d, MPI_Type_size:%d\n",sizeof(MPI_UINT64_T),tsize);
```

which shows the difference between the size of the `MPI_Datatype` and what you really want to know, the size of the `UINT64` type.

```
Size:4, MPI_Type_size:8
```

Answer (score 3):

`MPI_UINT64_T` is of type `MPI_Datatype`. The exact implementation of `MPI_Datatype` is not specified. For MPICH based MPI implementations (such as Cray's), that's s is usually an `int`, whereas in OpenMPI it's a pointer to a struct.

In any case,  your printf prints the `sizeof(MPI_Datatype)`, which has no relation to the actual bytesize of the type it stands for.

If you want to check whether the pointer (address) size in your system is 32 or 64 bit,  you could print `sizeof(void*)` or any other pointer type.

Comment: This is correct. You can see the value of `MPI_UINT64_T` in the `mpi.h` file associated with your implementation.